# How to pass data from a QuerySelectField in flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

In my application i have a QuerySelectField to populate a dropdown menu.
I get the choices details for the queryselectfield from the db. Once user select any choice from dropdown menu and click on Submit button which is a POST method, i want to pass the value that user selected from the dropdown to a db to store. But it always return the value None from the queryselectfield. So db stores the data as None.

models.py

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    resturant = db.Column(db.String(64))
    food = db.Column(db.String(64)))
```

forms.py

```
def possible_res():
    return Resturant.query.all()

def possible_menu():
    return Menu.query.all()

class OrderForm(Form):

    sel_res = QuerySelectField(query_factory=possible_res,
                               get_label='name')

    sel_menu = QuerySelectField(query_factory=possible_menu,
                                get_label='food',
                                allow_blank=False
                                )
    submit = SubmitField("Confirm")
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/resturant', methods=['GET','POST'])
def resturant():
    form = OrderForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        test = form.sel_menu.data
        return render_template("make_order.html", form=form, test=test)
    else:
        a = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).all()
        for u in a:
            name = u.firstname

        b = Orders(name=name, email=session['email'])
        b.resturant = form.sel_res.data
        b.food = form.sel_menu.data
        db.session.add(b)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QuerySelectField#__init__`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ext.html#wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField)'s `query_factory` argument should return a SQLAlchemy [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) object, not a Python list. WTForms will materialize the query itself, [by iterating over it](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/e79c858b865e7d84322389733178075c976b7543/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py#L98-L100).  Simply change your factory functions to return the `query` attribute, rather than the list:

```
def possible_res():
    return Resturant.query

def possible_menu():
    return Menu.query
```